# Awk extract fields with multiple separator

Tags: awk, files

File contents are like below

```
AB: 20190131  13 J-1|19:30:00.000000000 18:06:00.000000000 123466  50 @TEST . "" 1234 - I . ".." "" "" "TEST TEXT 1" "TEXT 2: Sr of human happiness. To obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find f.==Required file.csv.gz FIELD*SERVER-TIME*05:29:51.981378000" "" NoTime
AB: 20190131  1 J-1|19:30:00.000000000 18:06:00.000000000 123466  50 @TEST . "" 1234 - I . ".." "" "" "TEST TEXT 1" "TEXT 2: Sr of human happiness. To obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find f.==Required file2.csv.gz,Required file5.csv.gz FIELD*SERVER-TIME*05:29:51.981378000" "" NoTime
```

I want to print  3rd field followed by *csv.gz file name which comes as the first field for field separator (==)

Sample output like below

```
13,Required file.csv.gz
1,Required file2.csv.gz,Required file5.csv.gz
```

I am able to extract file name with below command

```
awk -F "==" '/.csv.gz/{print $2}' | awk '{print $1}'
```

But unable to get the third field in the same line.

Comment: Please, read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I don't see how `Required file.csv.gz` is the first field for `-F "=="`

Comment: Please drag the line for complete sentence

Comment: your command outputs just `Required`.

Comment: How would you know that the file name is `Required file.csv.gz` instead of `Required_file.csv.gz` or `This is a required file.csv.gz` if after your file name is another space ? What are possible file names ? For now, answers can only cover your current exact example.

Comment: Nice Point, will edit my post, Thanks

Comment: so, it has always the same filename extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `match()` with *RSTART*, *RLENGTH* and `substr()`:

```
awk 'match($0,/==.*?.csv.gz/){print $3","substr($0, RSTART+2, RLENGTH-2)}' file
```

**Where**

we use `match()` function to find the sub-string matching the pattern `/==.*?.csv.gz/`. For any matched lines, we will get *RSTART* and *RLENGTH* to identify the location and length of the matched text, then use `substr($0, RSTART+2, RLENGTH-2)` to retrieve the text (`+2` and `-2` to remove the leading '==' from the matched text).

Answer (score 0):

With one awk :

```
awk '{
        printf "%s,", $3
        match($0, /Required [a-z]+\.csv\.gz/, a)
        print a[0]
    }' /tmp/file
```

With 2 commands :

```
awk '{printf "%s,", $3}' /tmp/file
grep -oP 'f.==\KRequired \w+.csv.gz' /tmp/file
```

### Output

```
13,Required file.csv.gz
```

Comment: Missed a print statement in awk

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**Option 1:**

```
awk '{gsub(/f.==/, ""); print $3","$(NF-4)" "$(NF-3)}' file

13,Required file.csv.gz
```

- `gsub` will substitute "f.==" with null.
- print 3rd fields from start and 4th and 3rd filed from the end of the line

**Option 2:**

```
echo "`awk '{ print $3}' file && awk -F '==' '{print $2}' file| awk '{print $1" "$2}'`" | tr '\n' ','
```

- print the 3rd column with space as delimiter.
- parse 2nd column with "==" as delimiter and from that print 1st and 2nd column with space as delimiter.
- the transpose newline with comma

Note: option2 is only for one line input.

Comment: Can you plz explain how it works

Comment: @upkar check my update